# How to load big datasets like million song dataset into BigData HDFS or Hbase or Hive?

Tags: python, hadoop, hive, hbase, bigdata

I have downloaded a subset of million song data set which is about 2GB. However, the data is broken down into folders and sub folders. In the sub-folder they are all in several 'H5 file' format. I understand it can be read using Python. But I do not know how to extract and load then into HDFS so I can run some data analysis in Pig. 
Do I extract them as CSV and load to Hbase or Hive ? It would help if someone can point me to right resource.

Answer (score 1):

If it's already in the CSV or any format on the linux file system, that PIG can understand, just do a hadoop fs -copyFromLocal  to

If you want to read/process the raw H5 File format using Python on HDFS, look at hadoop-streaming (map/reduce)

Python can handle 2GB on a decent linux system- not sure if you need hadoop for it.

Comment: hadoop fs -copyFromLocal your_files HDFS_Path

Comment: I mainly wanted to know how to convert hierarchical data format (hdf5) file and load it onto hadoop fs. Since data is in multiple folders with metadata information, is there any easy way to load it onto a hive table.

Answer (score 0):

Don't load such amount of small files into HDFS. Hadoop doesn't handle well lots of small files. Each small file will incur in overhead because the block size (usually 64MB) is much bigger.

I want to do it myself, so I'm thinking of solutions. The million song dataset files don't have more than 1MB. My approach will be to aggregate data somehow before importing into HDFS.

The blog post "The Small Files Problem" from Cloudera may shed some light.